# What does "finished/kalah" mean in Genesis 2:1?

Tags: genesis

**Genesis 2:1**

> "Thus the heavens and the earth were **finished**, and all the host of them". ESV My emphasis.

A. **Finished for the moment**. Further creating will occur in the future.

B. **Finished absolutely and completely** in that no new types and kinds will occur. Only more examples of existing types will occur. e.g. **John 6:1-15**.

> "So they gathered them up and filled twelve baskets with fragments from the five barley loaves..".

Jesus made more loaves and fish, but grain and fish were created by the 6th day of the first week; Genesis 1.

Comment: Interesting point : that the miracles were a creative act. Metamorphosis was achieved (apparently, unless it was a falsified trick in fear of death by Pharaoh) by the magicians imitating Moses. But the miracles of Jesus require the work of the Creator. Up-voted +1.

Comment: I just thought of another post-creation-week creative act of God - the conversion of a soul which is called a new creation as per 2 Cor 5:17, Gal 5:16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people have tried to make more of the verb כָּלָה (kalah = complete/finished) such as:

1. All God's creative acts were forever finished.  This is obviously untrue as the OP correctly points out because many miracles involving lesser creative acts are recorded in the OT and NT.  Further, we are also told that God will create a new heaven and a new earth (Isa 65:17, 22, 1 Peter 3:13, Rev 21:1)
2. God's creation of variety is complete.  I am mystified by how this idea (as suggested by the OP) could be wrested from the text.  I doubt that God's creative acts of diversity will ever be complete
3. God's creation of our earthly home was complete.

The last of these meanings appears to be intended meaning precisely because in the very next verse we have the same word defined for us follows:

> Gen 2:2 - God **completed** on the seventh day His work which He had done,
> and rested ...

Note the triple parallel structure of Gen 2:1-3.  (There are also wonderful chiastic structures here that we will not consider.)

> 1. Thus the heavens and the earth **were finished**, and all the host of them.
> 2. And on the seventh day God **finished his work** that he had done, and he rested on the seventh day from all his work that he had done.
> 3. So God blessed the seventh day and made it holy, because on it God rested from all **his work that he had done in creation**.

Let us observe several things about what this passage says:

(a) God rested - this does not suggest or even imply that God permanently rested - it was a temporary rest on the seventh day

(b) The rest involved the rest from creating the world and environment suitable for life on earth.  Again, there is no hint that this rest was permanent as confirmed by  John 5:17 where God is declared to be always working.

(c) The rest is specifically designated as a rest from the work of the original creation of the world, not a rest from either creative acts nor a permanent rest from creativity and diversity.

Therefore, of the OP's options, I prefer option "**A**".